Please help me: Sending String from PyCharm via usb to NXT, which is programmed by Bricx CC
I am new on this platform and hope for some help.
I am doing a school project right now and we are working with Lego Mindstorms NXT and write the program with the Bricx Command Center. I know that this is pretty old but maybe some of you have tips or ideas. So my idea was to create the game rock paper scissors but in a way the player never wins. To do that I worked with the Mediapipe Hand gesture recognition I am running in PyCharm which works great. My webcam analyses the hand gesture.
We have to also work with the Bricx Command Center which works like this: I built a Lego hand and the thumb, index finger, and the rest of the fingers are connected to 3 motors. With those I can make the opposite gesture to the gesture the player made. So when the program analyses the players gesture I want it to send a string via USB to the NXT. The NXT knows the string and makes the corresponding gesture. But that's exactly my problem, because I also need a program written in the Bricx Command Center which can receive the string I send from PyCharm via USB. Are there any ideas or solutions how I could do that? It would be very helpful. I tried many things also asking ChatGPT but as we all know this isn't often that helpful.

Since you are using Bricx Command Center is it fair to presume that you're doing all of this in a Microsoft Windows OS environment?

nxt-python is a popular Python library that can communicate with an NXT via USB or Bluetooth.
Most of the APIs are designed to remotely control the NXT, but the Mailbox feature is useful to send information to a program that is running on the NXT.
I would expect that this should be compatible with the SendMessage and ReceiveMessage functions in NXC.
